# Django JavaScript Translation gettext is not defined

Tags: javascript, django

My javascript function contains the following:

```
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = gettext("This is an example");
```

My urls.py looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('project.urls')),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
```

And in my template I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
```

The translation above using gettext() does not work. A Reference Error comes up saying gettext() is not defined. However, in the same javascript file i have:

```
var monthNames =  [gettext("January"), gettext("February"), gettext("March"), gettext("April"), gettext("May"), gettext("June"), gettext("July"), gettext("August"), gettext("September"), gettext("October"), gettext("November"), gettext("December")];
```

And that does not prompt a reference error. The month translations work but the example one does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure, but try checking the order of your script. See, if you are using the gettext() function for the example above before the script tag where you load the javascript-catalog.

Comment: Good catch! But it didn't solve the issue. The error still comes up. Thanks though!

Comment: Check if other gettext() functions calls don't throw ReferenceError by removing the `document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = gettext("This is an example");` line. If they work fine, then most probably, it is some issue of the script loading later after your function call or any other scope issue.

Comment: Changing where the script is called doesn't do anything. The same error is  still there

Comment: Can you show more of your code, how are you calling the gettext() function in the `example` case above?

Comment: What I wrote above is how I call it. Those are the only two times that i use it. So I'm not sure what other code to share.

Comment: There is one thing you can do. Try setting the breakpoint on this line, and when the breakpoint happens, see from your Developer Tool's,  check whether the javascript-catalog file is loaded or not. If it is not, then you have to move your function where this line is written to below of the line where you are loading the javascript-catalog.

Comment: Or else, you can anyway move this line to the point where your month calls are working.

Answer (score 0):

I literally had the same exact issue, even when I had the script tag come before the gettext().

The simple fix was to make sure the catalog came before the app in urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
     ...
    <your app>
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is complete guideline to add Admin Date Picker in Front end.

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from django import forms
from .models import Student

class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Media:
        css = {
            'all': (
                '/static/admin/css/widgets.css',
            )
        }
        js = [
            # '/admin/jsi18n/',
            '/static/admin/js/core.js',
        ]
    
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = [
            "first_name",  
            "last_name", 
            "birth_date", 
        ]
        widgets = {
            'birth_date': widgets.AdminDateWidget()
        }
```

urls.py

```
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

add_student.html

```
<form action="{% url 'some_url' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
{{ form.media }}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
<script src="/jsi18n/"></script>
```

add this before jquery block. Hope this might help