# How use gettext in JS code correctly?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-i18n, django-1.11

In my Django project I have JS file with text with I need to translate. I use next code below.

With the help of *makemessages* and *compilemessages* commands I created *djangojs.po* and *djangojs.mo* files. The problem is JS code dont work correctly after adding **gettext**. It raise error in browser console. How to fix this problem?

**urls.py:**

```
from django.views.i18n import javascript_catalog

js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('slider',),  # my app name
}

urlpatterns = [
   [OTHER URLs]

    # Internationalization in Javascript Code
    url(r'^jsi18n/$',
        javascript_catalog,
        js_info_dict,
        name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

**JS:**

```
$("#slideModalBox").on("click", "#imageFieldClearBtn", function() {
    $('#imageFieldFileName').val("");
    $('#imageFieldClearBtn').hide();
    $('#imageFieldInput input:file').val("");
    $("#imageFieldInputTitle").text(gettext("Add new image"););
});

$("#slideModalBox").on("change", "#imageFieldInput input:file", function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $("#imageFieldInputTitle").text(gettext("Change Image")); <-- This place raise error
        $("#imageFieldClearBtn").show();
        $("#imageFieldFileName").val(file.name);            
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
});
```

**ERROR in browser console:**

```
ReferenceError: gettext is not defined
reader.onload http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/js/slider/image_field.js:12:9
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django JavaScript Translation gettext is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703529/django-javascript-translation-gettext-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `<script src="/jsi18n/"></script>` added in your base.html before your js script?

Comment: You was absolutely right! It works for me. Thank you! =)

Answer (score 0):

try to make the following order in your urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

 # Internationalization in Javascript Code
    url(r'^jsi18n/$',
    javascript_catalog,
    js_info_dict,
    name='javascript-catalog'),

# then the other urls
   [OTHER URLs]
]
```

basically, make the javascript_catalog first .

Or

- Change your system language settings, and see if it works . That means your langa\uage isn't supported yet

Comment: I tried it also but unfortunately dont work. Do you have any other ideas?