# Django i18n failing to catch strings in JS render functions

Tags: javascript, html, django, templates, localization

I'm using i18n to translate a Django project into various languages. Everything is nicely translated depending on locale, except for certain strings in JavaScript render functions. For example, if I run `django-admin makemessages --all` and `django-admin makemessages -d djangojs --all`, "Launch this app" and "App under review" from the HTML template below don't show up in any of the `django.po` or `djangojs.po` files, despite being tagged with `gettext()`:

```
<script>
  const renderStatus = () => {
    let launchApp = gettext("Launch this app");
    document.getElementById("component-appLauncher").innerHTML = `
        <span class="u-flex-grow-1" style="vertical-align: middle;">` + launchApp + `</span>
        <a href="#launch_this_app-modal">
          <button style="btn--sm">
            <i class="u-center fa-wrapper fa fa-solid fa-arrow-right-long"></i>
          </button>
        </a>
    `;

    let appReview = gettext("App under review");
    document.getElementById("component-appStatus").style.color = "red";
    document.getElementById("component-appStatus").innerHTML = appReview;
  }
</script>
```

Sometimes (though not consistently, and I can't reproduce this at will), one or the other .po file will have these lines (example from the Spanish translation), with no reference to the HTML template source file or line numbers:

```
#~ msgid "Launch this app"
#~ msgstr "Lanzar esta app"

#~ msgid "App under review"
#~ msgstr "App en estudio"
```

This seems to be related to the cache because, after a lot of tab refreshes, the translation will suddenly appear (even though the mapping is missing from the .po files), but I can't discern a consistent pattern to any of it.

Is this a bug in i18n? If not, any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django JavaScript Translation gettext is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42703529/django-javascript-translation-gettext-is-not-defined)

Comment: @IVNSTN Unfortunately not. I'm not seeing any errors but I'm starting to think that the issue is because the JS is inside a <script> tag in an HTML template file. I'm going to try moving the function to its own .js file and then importing that in the HTML.